# Rails (6.0.3.4) Webpacker (5.2.1) package import error: `Can't import the named export from non EcmaScript module`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I'm trying to import a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/react-form) into my Rails 6 project – I'm on `Rails 6.0.3.4` and `webpacker 5.2.1` gem.

- The package is installed `yarn add @shopify/react-form`
- It's imported into the file `import {useForm, useField} from '@shopify/react-form';`
- Now after running `./bin/webpack-dev-server`

I get this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@shopify/react-form/build/esm/validation/validator.mjs 35:25-32
Can't import the named export 'isEmpty' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

And few more of the same error but different file names.

I read on [another issue](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-component-library/issues/399) that adding a new rule to `webpack` would fix the issue, so I followed the instructions on the `webpacker` README:
[image]

The thing is I don't have `/config/webpack/base.js`, I created on anyway and created a `rules` directory in side the `/config/webpack/` directory, so my `base.js` looks like this:

```js
// /config/webpack/base.js
const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const fixConfig = require('./rules/fix')

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, fixConfig)
```

and the fix looks like this:

```js
// /config/webpack/rules/fix.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need help/guidance to figure out hot to solve this. TIA!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to fix the error, this [article](https://rossta.net/blog/how-to-customize-webpack-for-rails-apps.html#using-module-aliases) guided me to figure out how to merge a new rule into webpack config.

Here is what `environment.js` looks right now:

```js
// /config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.config.merge({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto"
      }
    ]
  }
})

module.exports = environment
```

Before it was:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

module.exports = environment
```

I ended up deleting `base.js` and `fix.js`.